# using requestWhenInUseAuthorization with swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have a question with regards to an app I'm making, the first page the loads up asks the user permission to use their location using **requestWhenInUseAuthorization** method. they either grant it or not which is fair enough, but without the location the app is useless.

My question is if they say No is there any way to programmatically ask for permission again ? Because **requestWhenInUseAuthorization** function doesn't really do anything once you've said no. The only way is to dig through the iOS settings and give permission, or delete the app and install it again. id like to avoid both options if possible.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2):

No there's not any way, unless the user enables it in their privacy settings.

The best method is to let them know in advance that you're asking for access, and present your own dialog before actually calling the authorization request. That way, when they say no, you don't actually decline the auth - you just don't show them the system dialog. Something like "Hey, to use this cool feature, we need access to your location". This way, you can have a setting within your app to turn on and off location if you wish.

Another thing to think about is only asking for permission once the user indicates that they want to use that feature - for example, don't ask for the location permission when the app is first loaded, ask for it when they try to use a location-based feature. They've already made the decision to give the app access, so they'll be more likely to accept.

Comment: All valid points, however there is no point to the app if the location is disabled. plus having a view that explains why location is needed then your own dialogue box then system dialogue box doesn't really make for good UX. The chances someone will say no are very unlikely, but i know some time people (including me) just want to use an app and press anything to get things going.

Comment: I'd argue that it's worse UX to make the user hunt through the system preferences if they accidentally hit no.

If you use a simple alert dialog, perhaps with an indicator to hit "ok", it will prime them to accept as well. Explain the reason, and people will likely accept more often than not.

Answer (score 2):

No, that popup is a one-time request. If they say no, however, you can prompt them to change their settings in a more helpful way by using the `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` constant. The [NSHipster article on Core Location](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/) has a good example.

Comment: This might just do the job. Even though its not ideal, its better than having people fumble around settings pages :) . I can totally see why apple have restricted the requestWhenInUseAuthorization to be a one time deal. having this message pop up all the time will be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Check `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()`.

1. If it returns `.NotDetermined`, you ask for authorization (`locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`)
2. If it returns `.AuthorizedWhenInUse`, you are fine
3. In all other cases you can do this to redirect the user to the appropriate place in settings where he/she can change the settings.

   ```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From func description:

```
func requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

**Description** 
Requests permission to use location services while the app is in the foreground.
When the current authorization status is notDetermined, this method runs asynchronously and prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location services.

The user prompt contains the text from the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file, and the presence of that key is required when calling this method.

After the status is determined, the location manager delivers the results to the delegate’s **locationManager(*:didChangeAuthorization:)*** method. If the current authorization status is anything other than notDetermined, this method does nothing and does not call the locationManager(:didChangeAuthorization:) method.